# xml deserialize to object c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

I have xml object in string which I want to deserialize to C# Object. I have test simple gender class and it worked fine but not sure why my other xml doc is not work

### xml

```
<StudentByPersonCode>
  <StudentByPersonCode list="1">
    <Item>
      <PERSON_CODE>33317</PERSON_CODE>
      <FORENAME>Louis</FORENAME>
      <MIDDLE_NAMES>Ane</MIDDLE_NAMES>
      <SURNAME>Sullivan</SURNAME>
      <TITLE>MISS</TITLE>
      <SEX>F</SEX>
      <DATE_OF_BIRTH>1/01/1998 00:00:00</DATE_OF_BIRTH>
      <PROGRESS_STATUS>A</PROGRESS_STATUS>
    </Item>
   </StudentByPersonCode>
 </StudentByPersonCode>
```

### Student Class Object

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("StudentByPersonCode")]
public class Student
{
    [XmlElement("StudentByPersonCode ")]
    public List<StudentListWrap> StudentListWrap = new List<StudentListWrap>();

    public WebServiceStatus WebServiceStatus { get; set; }
}

public class StudentListWrap
{
    [XmlAttribute("list")]
    public string ListTag { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public List<Students> Students = new List<Students>();

}


public class Students
{
    [XmlElement("PERSON_CODE")]
    public int PersonCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("TITLE")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("FORENAME")]
    public string Forename { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("MIDDLE_NAMES")]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("SURNAME")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("SEX")]
    public string Sex { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DATE_OF_BIRTH")]
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("PROGRESS_STATUS")]
    public string ProgressStatus { get; set; }
}
```

### Class to deserialize

```
 public static T DeserializeXMLToObject<T>(string xml) where T : class
    {
        T obj = null;
        StringReader strReader = null;
        XmlSerializer serializer = null;
        XmlTextReader xmlReader = null;
        try
        {
            strReader = new StringReader(xml);
            serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(strReader);
            obj = (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            //Handle Exception Code
            var s = "d";
        }
        finally
        {
            if (xmlReader != null)
            {
                xmlReader.Close();
            }
            if (strReader != null)
            {
                strReader.Close();
            }
        }
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(obj, typeof(T));
    }

}
```

### The XML doc that work fine

```
<Genders>
 <Genders list="1">
  <Item>
   <CODE>M</CODE>
   <DESCRIPTION>Male</DESCRIPTION>
  </Item>
  <Item>
   <CODE>F</CODE>
   <DESCRIPTION>Female</DESCRIPTION>
  </Item>
 </Genders>
</Genders>
```

### Gender Object class

```
 [Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Genders")]
public class Gender
{

    [XmlElement("Genders")]
    public List<GenderListWrap> GenderListWrap = new List<GenderListWrap>();

    public WebServiceStatus WebServiceStatus { get; set; }
}


public class GenderListWrap
{
    [XmlAttribute("list")]
    public string ListTag { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public List<Item> GenderList = new List<Item>();
}



public class Item
{
    [XmlElement("CODE")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DESCRIPTION")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: <Genders> is missed out while I pasted

Comment: the Gender class does deserialize but the Student one does't, I am not sure why?

Comment: I think it's only a spelling error. I proposed an answer therefore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose that you accidently added a space in this line:

```
[XmlElement("StudentByPersonCode ")]
```

Try this:

```
[XmlElement("StudentByPersonCode")]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the whitespace in [XmlElement("StudentByPersonCode ")], as @rbr94 has mentioned.

Second, the DateTime field is parsing incorrectly. The correct one would be, for example : 
`<DATE_OF_BIRTH>2011-01-10</DATE_OF_BIRTH>`. You don't need the hour there anyway for the date of birth.

The correct format for the date if it has to be parsed from XML would be:

> 2010-01-01T00:00:00

Comment: sure, but I don't any control of in coming xml doc, try to take string and then convert to date without time